# Is there any way to programmatically get the initial submitters for an approval process?

Tags: approval-process

It doesn't appear to be query'able via ProcessInstance or any of the related approval objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the SubmittedById field on the ProcessInstance system object. It's not in the documentation, but it can be queried